# WP7: Windows Phone 7: EventHandle seems looping

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1.1

I would like to have an `EventHandle` for a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event. When called/fired the last character of a `string` should be removed. My code looks like this:

```
 public string MyString;

 private void OnMouseDownDelete(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
     int MyStringLength = MyString.Length;
     MyStringLength = MyStringLength - 1;
     MyString = MyString.Substring(0, MyStringLength);
 }
```

But when I run this code a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event will start a loop until the `string` becomes empty.

Who can tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Mango (7.1), you can use the [Tap Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.tap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead of the MouseLeftButtonDown event.

However, I suspect that the event is firing multiple times which is causing the deletion of the string.

A good practice is to use the `Handled` property so that other control's do not try to handle the same event:

```
private void OnMouseDownDelete(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     int MyStringLength = MyString.Length;
     MyStringLength = MyStringLength - 1;
     MyString = MyString.Substring(0, MyStringLength);

     e.Handled = true;
}
```

You may need to post all the code that shows how the MouseLeftButtonDown event is being added.

Comment: Thank you. Working as expected.

Comment: Which worked? Changing to the `Tap` event? Or using `Handled=true`?

Comment: `Handled = true`Oh I see now. Do I get this right, I can add multiple `EventHandle`s to a single event? Okay, I can also take care to just add one. But is there a way to delete all `EventHandle`s at once?

Comment: That's correct. You can add several event handlers to an event. You cannot remove/delete all event handlers without using a lot of reflection. Events are based on subscriptions where you can set your own event handlers and remove your own event handlers; but you can not remove someone else's event handlers, i.e., the framework's.